# Search all columns of a table using a single where condition with single keyword in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have a table which consists of 64 different fields. i am going to search with a single keyword in it, Results should match the keyword from any field. Give some suggestions.

Comment: don't forget to click the tick and upvote answers that helped you.

Comment: ^I completely agree and have similar thoughts :)

Comment: select * from *where *like %search_text%. Is this possible ???

Comment: The fact that you need to do this kind of query suggests a problem with your schema. If all the fields contain the same kind of data, they should probably be rows of a table, not columns.

Comment: @Barmar I import wild CSV files into staging tables in my system and sometimes need to search more than field in the staging table to determine a fact that will belong to a single field in my core data table(s).

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table`
WHERE
CONCAT_WS('|',`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4`,`column64`) # single condition, many columns
LIKE '%VT%'
```

Voila.

The '|' separator, by the way, is to prevent you finding coincidental matches where, e.g., column1 ends in 'V' and column2 starts with 'T', which would give you a false positive in a search for "VT".

I'm not sure if the above method is faster than the `OR` method (I would guess they're the same speed) , but it definitely involves less typing if you're writing the query by hand.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the where with multiple condition with   `OR`

like

```
where
name = 'expected'
OR rate ='expected' 
OR country ='expected'
```

Comment: if i use OR , have to use all the 64 fields . is there any other solution for this ..?

Comment: Did you check my solutions in the same post?

Comment: @RegisteredUser For alternate solutions/suggestions (If he has concerns with multiple ORs).

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a way around your query being simple but long:

```
SET @term = "Somesearch";
SELECT id, title FROM sometable WHERE
    col1 LIKE '%@term%' OR
    col2 LIKE '%@term%' OR
    col3 LIKE '%@term%' ...;
```

Instead of using a MySQL variable, you can just use a language-specific variable but for the sake of examples, I thought I'd stick with MySQL itself.

The "..." is where you'd place the other 61 columns/fields.

Comment: This is tiny syntax but have to write loooooooooong codes :)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be to use FOR XML to get all columns to print to a single field... like this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (
SELECT a.*
,( SELECT *
   FROM table_to_search b
   WHERE a.KeyField = b.KeyField
   FOR XML RAW) AS `Full_Text_Record`
FROM table_to_search a) c
WHERE c.`Full_Text_Record` LIKE '%Search_string%'
```

Might take a while to run if it is a particularly large table, but it should brute force you to find out if that string exists in any given table.

Comment: What are the square brackets for? This is MySQL, not SQL-Server.

Comment: `FOR XML RAW` is a Microsoft SQL Server-ism, not supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to use multiple `ORs`.

```
select * from TAB where col1 like "%VAR%" OR col2 like "%VAR%" OR......col64 like "%VAR%";
```

You can use `like` or `=` as per the requirement, but it will require to change your query every time you add a new column.

As an alternative, you can take `SQLDump for that table` and then `search` that file.

With some Googling,

1. See if this project is useful - http://code.google.com/p/anywhereindb/. Searches all the fields and praised by many.
2. Try to use the information from `information_schema` table. Look for all the columns in the table. Now, try to form your query using this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you can translate this SQL Server syntax to MySQL

```
WHERE
name = @keyword OR
country = @keyword OR
department = @keyword OR
@keyword IS NULL -- match all when search text is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write one query that will generate a query for every column in your table.
In the example below the schema ("owner") is 'DEV_USER'
The table with your 64 fields is called 'CUSTOMER_INFO'
The criteria in the search is any column with a value of 'VT' in it:

```
select 'SELECT ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE '  || COLUMN_NAME || q'# LIKE '%VT%';#'
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS 
WHERE OWNER = 'DEV_USER'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'CUSTOMER_INFO';
```

This one query will generate a query for each field for you.
The results of running the above would be;

```
SELECT ADDRESS_1 FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE ADDRESS_1 LIKE '%VT%';

SELECT ADDRESS_2 FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE ADDRESS_2 LIKE '%VT%';

SELECT CITY FROM CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES_QASB
WHERE CITY LIKE '%VT%';

SELECT STATE_PROVINCE FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE STATE_PROVINCE LIKE '%VT%';

SELECT ZIP_POSTAL_CODE FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
WHERE ZIP_POSTAL_CODE LIKE '%VT%';
WHERE LATITUDE LIKE '%VT%';

... and so on for each column in the table
```

Then you just paste those queries that were generated from your first query into another tab and run them.

Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL to generate and execute a query that searches all the columns.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE searchAllCols(inDB VARCHAR(64), inTable VARCHAR(64), search VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
    SET @matches = (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '` LIKE "%', search, '%"') SEPARATOR ' OR ')
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = inTable and table_schema = inDB);
    SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `', inDB, '`.`', inTable, '` WHERE ', @matches);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL searchAllCols('table_to_search', 'searchString');
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. Unfortuntaly I get an ***ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `', inDB, '`.`', inTable, '` WHERE ', @matches);***

Comment: You have forgotten to reset the delimiter back to "**;**" and the last line won't execute.

Comment: What solves the  issue is putting the `CONCAT` query on a separate line before preparing the statement: `SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `', inDB, '`.`', inTable, '` WHERE ', @matches);`. Then we can do `PREPARE stmt FROM @query;`. It works in this way.