# Inverse SQL: SELECT column_name WHERE value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Let's assume we have table logins:

```
id| name  | lastname
---------------------
1 | mark  | johnson
2 | jack  | sparrow
3 | bruno | mark
```

We all know, that we can query SQL similiar to: `SELECT name FROM login WHERE id = 1;` and get in return `mark`.

I am looking for query like:

```
SELECT column_name FROM logins WHERE value = 'mark';
```

which will result in `name, lastname` or even

```
SELECT column_name FROM logins WHERE value = 'mark' AND id = 1;
```

which will result in `name`.

**EDIT:** The question is more complex than simple answers given. Real problem is how to select column name from 100+ columns, when we know expected value. For example we know that somewhere in table there is value `17,58`, but we want to find column name.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. Can you provide some more explanation of your problem ?

Comment: MySQL / PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Please explain your question. I cant understand it clearly.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550368/search-all-columns-of-a-table-using-a-single-where-condition-with-single-keyword)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql is similiar to what I am looking for. I will write some sh script which will do that for me.

Comment: 100+ columns??? Sounds to me like it's worth considering redesigning your database. E.g. if you can replace all your columns with one table with name-value pairs your "tricky" problem becomes "select keyname from keytable where value = 'value'"...

Comment: 100+ columns? That's scary.... Check your datamodel first, before you're in real deep trouble

Comment: The answer is very, very simple: Normalisation

Answer (score 1):

Getting the column name directly is not possible however using the case statement you can construct the query to return the column name for a matched value something as

```
select
id,
case 
 when name = 'mark' then 'name' 
 when lastname = 'mark' then 'lastname'
 else 'Nothing'
end as column_name 
from logins
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4afe/1)**

Comment: Well in this case we can just remove the 'Nothing' block and by adding the where at the end as `where name = 'mark' or lastname='mark'`

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can use the [hstore extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) for this (I don't think there is anything remotely similar available in MySQL):

```
with login_data as (
  select id, 
         skeys(hstore(l)) as column_name,
         svals(hstore(l)) as column_value
  from logins as l
  where avals(hstore(l)) @> array['mark']
) 
select id, column_name
from login_data
where column_value = 'mark'
;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/115d5/1

But the performance will most probably be quite horrible.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get mark if name in (name) Or in (lastname)
id think this will help You

```
SELECT column_name FROM logins WHERE ( name  = 'mark' Or lastname = 'mark') AND id = 1;
```

Comment: this does not make sense. If `id = 1` is in `WHERE` clause, you don't need to search by names.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this if you don't know id of the user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM logins WHERE name = 'mark';
```

Comment: This does not make sense at all.

Comment: What you wrote in a question make sense!?