# Quering all columns of single table in where condition for same input data

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

If we want to fetch information based on condition on single column, we do like this

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE firstName = 'james'
```

IF we want to put conditions on multiple columns, we do this

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE firstName = 'james' OR lastName = 'james' OR businessName = 'james'
```

But What if we have more than 50 columns.

Is there better way other than WHERE Condition with OR Keyword?
The approach should not involve writing all column names.

There is a way to do this in MySql as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613353/1800713).

Comment: No; if you want to search 50 columns, you're going to have to specify those 50 columns. Oracle isn't psychic (yet!).

Comment: @Boneist Got it. I paraphrased wrong question. What about all columns?

Comment: Do you not use a text editor with a column editing mode? It makes construction of a query with repetitive text very straightforward.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, Currently I am doing that. I need to do this for many tables. So i was trying to find better way which i found it is not possible.

Comment: You could always use SQL to help you generate the query? Are all the columns you're wanting to query in each table the same? Or is it all string fields you're wanting to check, etc? user_tab_columns will help you select all the columns for a table; you could then use that to write the query for you, filtering off the relevant columns for tables (eg. string columns)

Comment: @Boneist, Yes this is exactly what I am looking for. **Select all columns for a table to write query and filter the relevant columns**. The columns are different in each table.

Comment: depends on what you mean by relevant - I meant if you're looking for a string ('james') then you don't need to look in date or number columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to search all VARCHAR2 columns, then the following script ought to help:

```
set pages 0;
set lines 200

select case when rn = 1 and rn_desc = 1 then 'select * from '||table_name||' where '||column_name||' = ''james'';'
            when rn = 1 then 'select * from '||table_name||' where '||column_name||' = ''james'''
            when rn_desc = 1 then '    and '||column_name||' = ''james'';'
            else '    and '||column_name||' = ''james'''
       end sql_stmt
from   (select table_name,
               column_name,
               column_id,
               row_number() over (partition by table_name order by column_id) rn,
               row_number() over (partition by table_name order by column_id desc) rn_desc 
        from   user_tab_columns
        where  data_type in ('VARCHAR2')
        -- and   table_name in (<list of tables>) -- uncomment and amend as appropriate!
       )
order by table_name, column_id;
```

If you only want to search specific tables, you would have to put a filter in for the table_names you're after.

Running the above as a script will give you a script containing multiple queries that you can then run

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Thank you so much. You saved me a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can avoid writing all the column names,

But you can use an `IN` condition to make writing this a bit shorter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contact 
WHERE 'james' in (firstName, lastName, businessName)
```

Comment: I was afraid of this but I thought if this is possible in MySql. It might be in Oracle. I have shared a URL in the question.

Comment: @TusharBhaware: that answer is incorrect. The syntax shown there is for SQL Server not for MySQL.But most SQL Clients will allow you to easily select the columns from a popup or something similar

Comment: Yes. I am selecting all columns from SQL Client and then I am using them in query but I was tired of doing it after few tables. I need to this for a lot of tables so I was thinking of finding smart solution instead of doing this menial work.