# How to delete record from table if any of its cells contains value x?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `dbo.tblCars` with few foreign keys. Unfortunately some rows got corrupted and I got `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'` in some cells in multiple columns for some records.

What is the most straightforward way to remove record from table if any of its cells contains value `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search all columns of a table using a single where condition with single keyword in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550368/search-all-columns-of-a-table-using-a-single-where-condition-with-single-keyword)

Comment: @Whencesoever Fortunately it is MSSQL.

Comment: There are a number of ways you could approach this, but even though the link above is for MySQL, the solutions can still be used in SQL Server (albeit slightly different syntax for the concat, if you go that route, but the multiple `OR` clauses are the same in pretty much any version of SQL).

Comment: I guess the most straightforward way is to write DELETE statements for each column you have those values in, or write one delete statement with a WHERE clause that has (condition1 OR condition2 OR ...), it's difficult to say really as I don't know how many rows, table structure indexes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL like below

```
declare @query varchar(max)
select @query   =
    Stuff((
        select 'OR '+ 'cast('+c.name+' as varchar(max)) =''00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'' '
        from
            sys.columns c
         join sys.tables t on t.object_id=c.object_id
         and t.name ='dbo.tblCars'
         for xml path('')
         ),1,2,'')
set @query      = 'select * from dbo.tblCars where '+  @query  

exec (@query)
```